# Matching till function end

Tags: java, parsing, antlr, antlr4

I'm using [`ANTLR4`](http://www.antlr.org/) to parse some "simplified" C-style source code. My grammar is as follows:

```
grammar Language;

script: (include)* (functionDefinition)* EOF;

include: '#include' Blank FilePath Semicolon;

functionName: FileName;

functionDefinition: functionName '(' parameters ')' '{' functionBody '}';

functionBody: .*?; // This needs fixing

parameter: FileName;

parameters: parameter (',' Blank parameter)*;

FileName: AlphaCharacter WordCharacter*;

FilePath: FileName ChildFilePath*;

ChildFilePath: PathSlash FileName;

PathSlash: ForwardSlash | BackwardSlash;

ForwardSlash: '/';

BackwardSlash: '\\';

AlphaCharacter: [a-zA-Z];

WordCharacter: [a-zA-Z_0-9];

Blank: ' ';

Whitespace: (' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n');

Semicolon: ';';

SkipWhitespaces: Whitespace+ -> skip;
```

Given the following input text:

```
#include testWz/fdrf675tr\a56s;
#include testWz/fdrftr\s;

func1(param, par)
{
    if(true)
    {
        whatever();
    }
}

func2()
{

}
```

I implemented the following visitor to see what's going on:

```
public class ListenerPrinter extends LanguageBaseListener
{
    @Override
    public void enterInclude(LanguageParser.IncludeContext context)
    {
        System.out.println("[INCLUDE] " + context.FilePath().getText());
    }

    @Override
    public void enterFunctionDefinition(LanguageParser.FunctionDefinitionContext definition)
    {
        LanguageParser.ParametersContext parameters = definition.parameters();
        System.out.println("[FUNCTION DEFINITION] " + definition.getText());
        System.out.println("[PARAMETERS] " + parameters.getText());
        System.out.println("[BODY] " + definition.functionBody().getText());
    }
}
```

I would like to properly detect function bodies without breaking them down into their components yet since this is a lot more work of course. So far, the following output is produced:

```
[INCLUDE] testWz/fdrf675tr\a56s
[INCLUDE] testWz/fdrftr\s
[FUNCTION DEFINITION] func1(param, par){if(true){whatever();}}func2(){}
[PARAMETERS] param, par
[BODY] if(true){whatever();}}func2(){
```

The function body is too long and includes the next function's definition as well. One idea would be detecting the next closing bracket + the amount of opened brackets found in between but I'm not sure how to do this with grammar rules alone.

Comment: Does your "simplified" C allow a function to contain nested { ... } ? You imply that with the phrase *detecting ... the amount of opened brackets found in between*.   If so, a simple regex cannot pick up the function body because regexes can't match arbitrary brackets.   If  not, your simplified C is unrealistic and it is unclear what you will learn by doing this exercise on an unrealistic language, that you will be able to use somewhere else.

Comment: @IraBaxter: It's not an unrealistic language since it exists as a scripting engine. Also I'm not sure what you mean with nested { ... } since regular `if` and `while` loops exist but no "function nested in another function" which would be quite unusual anyway

Comment: Are  you allowed to have nested { ...  } ?   e.g.,  if c {  ... if d { } ... } ?  That very common.   A language that does not allow them is very uncommon.

Comment: Yes it does support all "usual" control flow syntax

Answer (score -1):

functionBody is a match-all rule. The non-greedy modifier doesn't help here as the rule itself has no terminating token. So try removing it and instead put the the wildcard matching into the `functionDefinition` rule:

```
functionDefinition: functionName '(' parameters ')' '{' .*? '}';
```

or alternatively move the curly braces to the `functionBody` rule:

```
functionDefinition: functionName '(' parameters ')' functionBody;
functionBody: OpenCurly .*? CloseCurly;
```

Note: I used lexer rules for the curly braces by intention. It's recommended to define all lexer tokens in own rules instead implicitly in the parser rules (avoiding so trouble like multiple definitions, automatically assigned token names etc.).

---

## UPDATE

I wasn't aware the required solution should support nested blocks delimited by curly braces (the entire question could need some polishing, that's why there are 3 close votes). The general principle for a solution is that you define one or more rules that explicitly define the curly braces pair so that the rule(s) are only matched if the opening and closing braces are balanced. You could do it like this:

```
functionBody: OpenCurly .*? (functionBody .*?)? CloseCurly;
```

i.e. recursively define `functionBody` as containing itself.

Comment: Both of your suggestions still yield the same (incorrect) result so maybe I still have to describe everything? But that shouldn't be necessary :(

Comment: @MikeLischke:  OP tells us that { ...  } in his language nest arbitrarily deep.   You are using a regex to attempt to match a function body by finding the outermost { }.   Pure regexes can't recognize nested parenthese of any kind, so this answer cannot be correct.

Comment: I think your answer is still wrong:  *.? is really dangerous; in particular, it can accept "{" or "}" so your recursive rule doesn't really detect matching { ... } .  OP probably intends his language to allow comments or strings; you don't account for braces in comments or strings.   You would be technically right to argue he didn't specify those, and wrong in terms of any real utility of a provided answer if you didn't cover these.

Comment: `*.?` denotes a non-greedy wildcard match in ANTLR4, so it will stop at the following token and not consider that as being part of the wildcard match.